# Site thumbnail in community bulletin for blog posts changes between main site and meta

Tags: bug, community-bulletin

I am not sure if this is intentional or desired behaviour, but the thumbnail for the pinned community blog post in the community bulletin changes depending on whether you view it on the main site (where you see the usual red site logo) or our meta site (where you see the meta "grayed-out" version of our site logo).

[image: Blog community bulletin thumbnail on main site]  [image: Blog community bulletin thumbnail on meta]

Is this behaviour intentional?

Comment: Also, the tooltip on the icon says "Mathematics Meta Stack Exchange". It would make sense for _blog_ links to have main site icon/tooltip, regardless from where they are viewed.

Comment: This is semi-intentional if I'm not mistaken, in the sense that basically we simply pluck from the current site data (since that's the only blog that'll come up other than the SE blog). But I can get this looked at.